# Fully inline non-static citations

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-word-2010

I would like to have fully inline non-static citations in my text that do not fit with the default form of "(author et al., year)", though I would like to keep those also.

Basically I would like to be able to have a sentence run as such:

```
"Indeed, further work by authors such as Kim and Cagnon has shown..."
```

Where "Kim" and "Cagnon" are non-static citations (with or with out the year) of separate publications.

Is this possible?

Comment: To be precise, are "Kim" and "Cagnon" authors of different publications, or are they first and second author of the same publication? (I have no clue about how to do this with Word; just for clarification)

Comment: They are authors of separate publications; will edit OP.

Comment: @pnuts As per the question. Normal word inline citations are of the format described, for example the same sentence currently runs as follows: `"Indeed, further work by many authors (Kim, 2008; Cagnon, 2002) has shown..."` i.e. The citations appear as a separate item within the sentance, whereas I would like the citations to become part of the flow of the sentence instead.

Comment: @pnuts, The comment is what I have the Q is what I want. Im not sure what you mean by hyperlinking...

Comment: Yup paper, my bad I could have stated that in OP. It's part of a formal thesis. From your link I may "Create a hyperlink to a location in the current document or Web page" and see how that works out... Ta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no good way to achieve this I'm afraid, this is mainly because Word only allows one style of citation in a document in order to keep a consistent look throughout the whole document. Therefore there really is no other choice but to choose between either your casual style or the APA style.

The closest you could get to "bending" the citation to look as you want without changing style can be achieved by adding each source as a separate citation instead of adding two sources to one citation, writing out the separating text as plain text and finally right clicking on each citation and choosing **Edit Citation** and click **Suppress Year**. The result should look something like `Indeed, further work by authors such as (Kim) and (Cagnon) has shown...`. Not perfect but it might do for you.

If you could settle for casual style of citation throughout your whole document then you could achieve this by creating your own bibliography style. Word stores these styles in XML form to the directory Word was installed to. If you are looking at doing this sort of thing then I highly suggest looking at [BibWord](http://bibword.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BibWord&referringTitle=Documentation) which is a tool that helps make it easier to create new bibliography styles. They also have plenty of existing custom styles that can be used.

Comment: Thanks @Adam, for the definitive answer. I'll have to stick with the APA style throughout then as this is for a thesis. In this particular case though I already have an APA style citation to these two authors a paragraph or two preceding this sentance, so allowed that the informal style would be OK if it was achievable, as it makes better reading. Ah well.